# Automated Coded UI Tests on Team Foundation Service throws "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" exception

Tags: coded-ui-tests, azure-devops

If I add a Coded UI Test to either our WPF or MVC project, it causes this error in the CI build. Is Team Foundation Service missing something to allow Coded UI tests to run? I tried referencing the dlls locally, but I'm assuming they are trying to reference something that is in my GAC that isn't on the TFS machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automated coded UI tests are not supported by the Team Foundation Service because the hosted build service cannot be run in interactive mode. I've added a feature request on [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3873350-support-interactive-mode-on-team-foundation-build-), but as of now the only way to automate coded UI tests is to run them on premises build controller. Steps to do so can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330987).

Comment: Looking into this as well.  Gave your UserVoice request a +3.

Comment: is this answer still true for TFS 2015?